# Accessing Outlets from Different Files

Tags: swift

I have a viewController with a bunch of labels.  Each label has an outlet in that viewController.

I want the functions that operate on those labels to be in a different file.  How do I access them?

Simplified example:

```
// File 1: VC1
class testScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()\
        
        formatLabel()
    }
}



// File 2: Functions

func formatLabel() {
    myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

(There are actually a lot of labels and fields and functions.  I want to break everything up into small, manageable files.)

Comment: Never do this. `@IBOutlet` should never be accessed outside its own view controller. (There are few things I put "never" in front of. This is one.) Move your logic into a "view model" (a non-VC object that tracks state) or just a model (an object that is nothing but state), and have the ViewController observe it.

Comment: Files is a slightly irrelevant concept in all this.  `myLabel` is a variable that is part of a `testScreen` instance.  To access it as you're showing, `formatLabel` needs to be a `testScreen` method.

Comment: Sorry, I am new and don't understand.  Suppose I have 20 labels, 20 fields, 20 functions, etc. I could end up with thousands of lines of code in a single file.  If I wanted all the functions that formatted the labels in one file, all the functions that formatted fields in another, and all the mathematical functions in another, and so on, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: "formatLabel needs to be a testScreen method." Correct. "Suppose I have 20 labels, 20 fields." Then you probably need to split your ViewController up into smaller pieces and compose them. "f I wanted all the functions that formatted the labels in one file" This isn't meaningful. "Formatting labels" is not a thing. You format *data*, and that's done in a view model generally. Similarly "mathematical functions" are not a category. *Everything* is a mathematical function in a computer program. You should place computation along with the data it manipulates.

Comment: Do not split up your logic according to whether you think it's "a mathematical function" or a "a formatting function." These aren't different things. Split up your logic according to the data it operates on and the output it creates. "Doing math" is not a category.

Comment: "There are actually a lot of labels and fields and functions." This suggests you want smaller ViewControllers. A ViewController manages a part of the screen. It doesn't have to manage the entire screen. https://vimeo.com/291601827

Comment: Let me ask in a different way.  Suppose I have 20 variables, 30 (complex) mathematical algorithms (one of which requires all 20 variables).  I want to display the results and format both the inputs and results according to some criteria.  Suppose all that ends up being 50 functions (math, formatting, whatever - doesn't matter). I just don't want 8000 lines of code in one file.

Comment: Actually, the math functions are easy since I can move data in and out of variables defined elsewhere.  It's the formatting functions that need to act upon the outlets, each of which may be quite long, that I am trying to organize by moving them to other files.

Comment: @RobNapier: do you suggest using a different view controller for each variable?  What if the variables all had mutual dependencies?

Comment: If the logic is complex (which it must be if there are all these inter-dependencies), then move all of this logic into the model or a view model. The View (which includes the ViewController) should just display the current state of the model. Search for MVVM for how view models work. If you have a ton of inter-dependency within dozens of elements in a View Controller, your View Controller is doing too much. It is time to refactor. But in no case should another object reach into a VC and modify its IBOutlets. If you need that, refactor so you don't.

Comment: Let me approach my question in differently:  Suppose I have a view with 10 variables.  Each is formatted in its own way and has its own (long - pretend each is 100 lines) function.  Should I have that 1000+ lines of code in a single file?  (If the answer is yes, what if I just WANT smaller, bite-sized, pieces.)  Is there a "good" way to way to break it up into different files?

Comment: Suppose I want to reuse those functions on other screens (for example, using `shouldChangeTextIn` to validate user input on a dozen different screens)  How do I (can I) reuse a function that needs to read from, write to, format an outlet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to comment on the "best practices" to solve your organization problem, but according to your requirement, you would do this with extensions.

```
// File1.swift

class testScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()\
        
        formatLabel()
    }
}
```

```
// File2.swift

extension testScreen {
    func formatLabel() {
        myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

Comment: I would actually love to hear what you have to say about best practices in this situation.  I want to know how to handle multiple functions that operate on elements that have mutual dependencies, and are on a single screen, without creating one enormous file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "have mutual dependencies", but I would take Rob Napier's advice and keep view controller code to a bare minimum. For example, if I had to update a label based on a mathematical calculation, I would create a separate class to handle the math. This class would be entirely unrelated (and unaware) of the labels that would eventually be displaying the result. It would only provide functions to, say, intake a couple numbers, perform a calculation, then return the result. Then you could just call this from the view controller and update the label with the result.

Comment: If you want more specific advice, I would recommend creating a new Stack overflow question and perhaps tagging me in it, since there's not enough room in the comments to fully address it (nor should a separate question be addressed in the comments).